# Merging 2 ActiveRecords of same type into one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an active record association below

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lineitems, dependent: :destroy
end

class Lineitem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

I have 2 Orders with different line items.

I want to merge these 2 orders to a new order and then delete the previous 2 records.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this, without creating new lineitems?

What I want is the same lineitems pointing to the new Order. Instead of making new copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by this way:

1. Create new order

   `new_order=Order.create #Pass additional parameters to create method if needed`
2. Take all LineItem which is belongs to other two orders. E.g. orders with ids 1 and 2.
   And attach all `LineItems` to `new_order`:

   `LineItem.where(order_id: [1, 2]).update_all(order_id: new_order.id)`
3. Delete old orders

   `Order.where(id: [1, 2]).destroy_all`

Answer (score 0):

```
o1 = Order.find(1)
o2 = Order.find(2)

# create new one, and assign lineitems to the new order

o3 = Order.create(...)
o3.lineitems = o1.lineitems + o2.lineitems

# destroy the old order
o1.destroy
o2.destroy
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: In this solution lineitems got deleted the moment o1 and o2 got destroyed. It works fine if o1 and o2 exist.